# ヘルプセンター翻訳：レビューキュー記事を日本語に訳しましょう！

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ, レビュー

翻訳をしてくれた [@supa](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/32986/supa)、[@cubick](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)、[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) に感謝します。

---

今年は [レビューキューの改善](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview) に取り組みました。ここで大切なステップは、ヘルプセンターにレビューキューに関する新しいセクションを設けることです。

#### なぜ大切ですか？

レビューキューに関する情報のほとんどは [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) のwiki投稿に集められています。これらの投稿は詳しく書かれており、キューの仕組みに関するすべてのニュアンスが含まれていますが、これは初心者のユーザーにとっては少し難しいかもしれません。

今回のイニシアチブの目的は、レビューキューの操作を最近始めたユーザーが、各レビューキューの基本的な仕組みをすばやく理解できる場所を設けることです。

#### レビューキューの記事を日本語に翻訳するお手伝いをお願いします

数週間前、わたしたちはヘルプセンター記事の最初のドラフトを作成し、[MSEに投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356120/274323) しました。コミュニティからのフィードバックに基づき記事を完成させ、[スタック・オーバーフロー](/help/review-queues) を含む[多言語サイトのヘルプセンターに追加](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues) しました。

本投稿への回答として現在のバージョンのヘルプ記事を英語で投稿しますので、日本語への翻訳サポートをいただければ幸いです。正確な翻訳を作成できるのは日本語版ユーザーの皆さんであると私たちは信じています。翻訳が仕上がり次第、随時ヘルプセンターに追加してゆきます。

既存の翻訳を改善するにあたり遠慮などは不要です！必要に応じて文章がより自然で明確になるように変更したいと思います。そして、こちらの回答欄からヘルプセンターの記事を最新の状態に保つように努めてまいります！

#### ヘルプセンターのレビューキュー記事

- ✅[レビューキューとは何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3430/78)
- ✅[初めての回答投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3676/78)
- ✅[初めての質問投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3677/78)

  - ✅[初めての投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/78)「初めての質問/回答投稿キューを使用するには？」が新たに追加されたため削除完了
- ✅[レビューキューが停止されたのはなぜ？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3431/78)
- ✅[低品質な投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3432/78)
- ✅[編集の提案キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3434/78)
- ✅[クローズ票のキューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3435/78)
- ✅[再オープン票キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3436/78)
- ✅[遅延回答キューを使用するには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3437/78)

Comment: This topics are very helpful for us! Let me help transrating some of them. Can I replace an answer into Japanese **directory** and remove the original text in raw English? (The text remains in history, of course.) | 翻訳した人は回答を日本語に直接上書きしていいですか？(もちろん履歴は残ります)

Comment: Or is it better to write a translation for each paragraph and leave the original English visible? | それとも段落ごとに訳文を書いて、原文の英語が見えるように残した方が良いのでしょうか。

Comment: @payaneco 編集履歴からいつでも原文は参照できるので、直接の編集で構わないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### レビューキューとは何ですか？

コミュニティによるサイトモデレーションの方法の1つとして、ユーザーやシステムによってレビューが必要であると識別された投稿をレビューし、投稿がサイトに有益であるかどうかを判断することがあげられます。信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues を達成するとレビューキューの最初のセットにアクセス可能となり、信用度が上がるにつれてさらに多くのキューにアクセスできるようになります。

レビューキューには投稿が1つずつ表示されるため、必要なアクションがあるかどうかをあなたが評価することになります。各キューには個別のオプションが用意されているので適切なアクションを実行できるでしょう。1つ目には、新規ユーザーによる初めての投稿を確認するアクションがあります。他には、信用度の低いユーザーによる編集の提案や、クローズや再オープンを決めるために質問を評価するアクションがあげられます。

各キューには特定の目的があり、以下のヘルプセンター記事に詳細が書かれています。

- [初めての質問投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) - 信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues。このキューの目的はサイトにまだ不慣れであるかもしれないユーザーを支援することです。このキューには新規ユーザーによって初めて投稿された質問が含まれます。
- [初めての回答投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) - 信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues。このキューの目的はサイトにまだ不慣れであるかもしれないユーザーを支援することです。このキューには新規ユーザーによって初めて投稿された回答が含まれます。
- [遅延回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers) - 信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues。このキューには、質問が投稿されてから回答が投稿されるまでの経過時間が比較的長いものが含まれています。これらの投稿を確認することで、質の良い新しい回答がきちんと表示され、スパムなど問題のある回答が削除されます。
- [トリアージ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow サイト限定 - 信用度 500。トリアージの主な目標は、そのままでよいか、コミュニティによる編集が必要か、或いはクローズや通報の必要があるかなど、質問をグループにすばやく分類することです。
- [低品質な投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) - 信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing。このキューにはシステムで生成された品質スコアやユーザーからの通報に基づいて品質が低いと判断された投稿が含まれています。
- [編集の提案](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits) - 信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing。[他の人の投稿を直接編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)するには、信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing が必要です。 十分な信用度を保持しないユーザーが編集を送信すると、提案された変更がこのキューに入ります。
- [クローズ票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close) - 信用度 $Privilege-CloseQuestion。質問が Stack Overflow のフォーマットや範囲に適さない場合には、クローズされる必要があります。アクティブなクローズ票や、クローズ通報された質問がこのキューに表示されるため、他の人はそれらをクローズする必要があるかどうかを確認します。
- [再オープン票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen) - 信用度 $Privilege-CloseQuestion。クローズされた質問が編集された場合や、他の人がクローズに同意しない場合、再オープンすることができます。再オープン票がアクティブな質問や、クローズ後70日間に本文が編集された質問は、このキューに表示されます。

注意： 初めての質問/回答投稿と遅延回答のキューは[メタサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)にはありません。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### レビューキューが停止されたのはなぜ？

*レビューキューの概要やその仕組みについては、[こちらのページ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)をご覧ください。*

レビューの一時停止とはペナルティではなくレビュー権限の一時的な保留です。正しくレビューする方法について学ぶ時間を得ることを目的としています。不十分なレビューは、コミュニティやサイトのコンテンツに悪影響を与えてしまいます。複数のタスクで誤ったアクションを取った場合、レビュー権限が一時的に停止され、この期間中はレビューキューにアクセスできなくなります。

レビューが停止されると、レビューキューナビゲーションドロップダウンに停止メッセージが表示されます。さらなる詳細については、[レビューキューダッシュボード](/review)とキューで確認できます。このメッセージは停止期間が終わるまで表示されます。

[image: Screenshot of the Review Queue dropdown in two states, first, during a suspension where the review suspension message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges are suspended until Jul 24. Click to learn more.") is visible but none of the review queues are and second after the suspension is over but the review message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges were suspended for 7 days. Click to learn more") is still visible.]

サイトへのアクセスの合い間にレビューが停止されることもあります。停止期間が終わった後であってもレビュー停止が発生したことは通知されます。メッセージを確認して承認すると通知は破棄されます。

### レビューが停止されている間はどうすればいいですか？

停止のお知らせをよくお読みください。より適切なアクションが行えるよう、レビュー停止に至ったタスクを見直してください。そして停止の際に提供されるリソースリンクを確認してください。停止中であっても各キューの統計ページと履歴ページへはアクセスが可能です。停止に至ったレビュータスクについて質問がある場合は[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)に質問を投稿し、`[review-suspension]` タグを使用してください。投稿には必ず次の情報を含めてください：

- 停止の原因となったレビューへのリンク
- あなたが取ったアクションについての説明（停止が間違っていると感じる場合は特に重要です）
- どれが正しい選択だったのか、その理由を理解したいという旨のリクエスト

今後は、もう少し時間をかけて見直し、十分な注意を払いながら各タスクを行うようにしてください。何が正しいアクションであるのかがわからない場合には [スキップ] 機能を利用して他の誰かにレビューを処理してもらうようにしましょう。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 低品質な投稿キューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing で利用可能*
他のユーザーから問題があると[通報](/help/privileges/flag-posts)されたり、システムから品質が低い可能性があると認識された投稿は、低品質の投稿キューに入ります。例として、以下が含まれます。:

- 非常に短く、間違った言語を使用していたり、意味不明な質問や回答。
- 回答として書かれた新しい質問やフォローアップの質問。
- 尋ねられた質問に答えようとしない回答やリンクのみで説明がないもの。
- 回答として入力されたコメント（「私も同じ問題を抱えています」や「すばらしい回答をありがとう」など）。

間違った回答とは私たちの定義では「低品質」ではないということを心にとめておくことが大切です。間違った回答は、問題を説明するコメントを受けるか、通報ではなくマイナス票を投じられる必要があります。

### 基本的なワークフロー

まず、投稿が質問か回答かを確認します。ページ上部に「質問」または「回答」のラベルが付けられます。このキューの投稿の多くは回答になります。

- オントピックで、十分に詳細が記載されていて、範囲が広すぎない質問については、**良い**を選択します。たとえ正しくないような回答であったとしても、質問に答えようとしている回答にはこのオプションを使用します。
- 投稿の品質が良く投稿をさらに改善できる場合には**編集**してください。レビューから投稿が取り除かれてしまうため、クローズ又は削除すべき投稿を編集することはやめてください。
- 回答が質問にまったく対応していない、リンクのみである、または理解できない場合は、**削除の推奨**または**削除**を選択してください。単に間違っている回答を削除するために投票することはやめてください。回答の問題を説明するコメントを残す、或いは定型コメントの1つを選択することも可能です。
- 質問をクローズする必要があると思われる場合は、**クローズの推奨**または**クローズ**を選択して下さい（参照：[質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](/help/closed-questions)）。
- 投稿の品質がよくわからない場合は**スキップ**してください。

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029)"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

2022/02/08 追記
[「初めての投稿」キューが「初めての質問」「初めての回答」キューに分割され](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3672/14055)、二つのページの追加がヘルプセンターで完了したため英語版に合わせてこちらは削除いたしました。

---

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 初めての投稿キューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues で利用可能*
初めての投稿キューには、質問や回答をするための最良の方法やスタック・オーバーフローでのオントピック/オフトピックをまだ完全に理解していないかもしれない新規ユーザーによって作成された最初の投稿が含まれます。スタック・オーバーフローに参加する際のルールなどサポートが必要であるかもしれないユーザーや、改善を必要とする可能性の高い投稿などに少し注意を払うことが、このキューの目的です。

### 基本的なワークフロー

レビューを行う時には、1つだけ或いはいくつかのアクションを実行することもできますし、何も実行しないという場合もあるでしょう。あなたが必要だと判断したアクションを実行してください。例えば、オントピックで良い質問であってもフォーマットのヘルプが必要な場合などです。その場合はフォーマットを改善できるように編集し、必要に応じて [完了] をクリックする前にプラス票を投じることもできます。

- この投稿に対して対処する必要がない場合は［**対処の必要なし**］
- 以下のアクションを行った場合には［**完了**］を選択して下さい :

  - プラス票やマイナス票を**投じる**。
  - 投稿は明確でガイドラインを満たしていたものの、文法やスペル、フォーマットなどの改善が必要で**編集**（或いは編集の提案）を行う。
  - **コメント**欄に（または既存のコメントにプラス投票し）、何が欠落しているか調整が必要なのかを指摘する。これらのコメントは投稿者と他のレビューアーの両方に役立ちます。
  - スパムや暴言、またはリンクのみで回答に質問に回答しようとしない投稿を**通報**する。
  - [信頼できるユーザー](/help/privileges/trusted-user)は、質問に回答しようとしない、リンクのみ、他の回答と重複している回答の**削除に投票**することが可能です。
- 確信が持てない場合には [**スキップ**]

タスクを却下するにはユーザーからの1回のレビューで十分です。よって、質問が本サイトの期待値に届くかどうかを注意深くレビューするように心がけてください。レビューを行い、実行するアクションを決めるためのガイドラインはこちらです :

#### すべての投稿について

- 投稿がスパムであったりプロモーションリンクが含まれている場合は、「スパム」と通報します。
- 投稿が不快な場合は、「失礼または暴言」として通報します。

#### 質問について

- 質問の主要部分がオフサイトでホストされずに投稿に含まれていることを確認してください。他のサイトへのリンクがある場合はリンクが壊れたり変更されても質問自体が成り立つ様に書かれていなければなりません。
- 良い質問とは :

  - 明確である。
  - 回答するために必要なすべての情報が含まれている。
  - オントピックである。
  - 事実に基づいた回答を求めている。
  - リサーチ済みである。
  - 適切なタグが付けられている。
- 必要に応じて、不足している情報をコメントで尋ねて質問の範囲を狭めるか、サイトの質問範囲に合うように質問を言い換えるようにしましょう。
- 以前に見たことがあるように思われる質問は、投稿が重複していないかをご確認ください。
- 新しいユーザーを励ますためにも、上手く書かれた質の良い質問にプラス票を投じてください。
- 質問をクローズしなければならない場合もあります。[通報する](/help/privileges/flag-posts)、或いはクローズ票を投じて質問をクローズすることができます。質問のクローズについては[こちら](/help/closed-questions)をご覧ください。

#### 回答について

- 投稿者が、単純なコメントや新しい質問の投稿ではなく、焦点を絞った回答をしようとしているかどうかを確認してください。
- これまでに投稿された他の回答とは異なるものでなければなりません。
- リンクが壊れていない、またはリンクだけで構成されていない投稿でなければなりません。

効果的に編集する方法の詳細については、ヘルプ記事「[自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか？編集はどのように機能しますか？](/help/editing)」をご覧ください。

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030)"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 編集の提案キューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing で利用可能*
編集の提案キューの主な目的は、信用度 $Privilege-PostEditing 以下のユーザーによって提案された編集が、投稿に有益かどうかを確認することです。提案された編集は、元の投稿者の意図を変えることなく文法やスペル、フォーマットの改善に焦点を当てるべきです。

信用度 $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits を持つユーザーの場合、このキューにタグ Wiki 編集の提案が表示されることがあります。これらのレビュー処理の詳細については、[タグ Wiki 編集の承認について](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)の権限ページを参照してください。

### 基本的なワークフロー

編集の概要を読み、元の投稿と編集の違いを確認することから始めましょう。タイトル（および質問の場合はタグ）が編集されているかどうか、そして投稿者がコメントに何らかの情報を残していないかを確認してください。

- 編集によって投稿が改善され、追加の編集が不要な場合は**承認**します。
- 編集が適切であっても不完全な場合は**編集を改善**し、編集ウィンドウを使用して未解決の問題を修正します。
- 編集が不要、破壊的、または元の作者の意図に反する場合は**却下**します。
- 提案された編集によって投稿が悪化したり、投稿に関する重大な問題が解決されなかったりした場合には**却下して新たに編集**します。そして、編集ウィンドウが開き、投稿を改善できるようになるので、あなたの編集を追加してください。
- 投稿が改善されたかどうかわからない場合は**スキップ**してください。

### 一般的な承認理由

- 追加情報を編集し既存の回答を明確にする。
- 投稿の文法やスペル、フォーマットやその他の小さな間違いを改善する。
- コメントにある情報を編集する。
- より多くの情報が利用可能であったり何かが変更された場合に回答を更新する。
- ソースや引用リンクを追加する。

### 一般的な却下理由

編集を却下する場合は却下理由を選択する必要があります。以下は編集の提案を却下すべき主な理由です：

- スパムや荒らし行為

  - 関連性のない、属性のないプロモーションリンクや製品の言及が追加される。
  - 投稿の内容にダメージを与え、損なう。
- 全く改善が行われていない

  - 不要なコンテンツやフォーマットの変更、または投稿をより混乱させるもの。
  - 不要な文法、スペル、またはスタイルの変更。
- 無関係なタグ

  - タグは、質問の主題を明確に示す必要があります。無関係で正しくないタグを追加する編集は却下してください。
- 投稿者の意図と明らかに矛盾

  - 元の投稿を読んだときとは非常に異なり、投稿を変更して反対のことを言ってしまっている。
- 返信を試みる

  - 明確化のリクエストをしたり投稿者への質問をコメントや回答欄の代わりに行う。
- 危害を加える

  - この理由は、提案を防ぐ必要があり上記のいずれにも当てはまらない、または上記のいくつかに当てはまる場合に使用できます。他のレビューアーがあなたの行動を理解できるように、提案の却下理由を説明する必要があります。

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539)"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### クローズ票のキューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-CloseQuestion で利用可能*

クローズ票のキューには、他のユーザーによってクローズする必要があると通報された質問が含まれます。このキューを確認する前に、どのような種類の質問をクローズすべきで、反対にクローズすべきではないかを、理解しておく必要があります。その詳細情報については、次の2つのヘルプページを参照してください :

- [質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](/help/closed-questions)のヘルプ記事はネットワーク全体のガイドで質問をクローズする必要がある主な理由が述べられています。クローズは通常、次の場合に発生します :

  - サイト上で既に存在する質問の[重複](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)である。
  - 回答するためにより詳細に、または明確にする必要がある。
  - 既存の質問の範囲が広すぎるため、より焦点を絞る必要がある。
  - 客観的に正しい答えが得られそうにもない、意見に基づく質問である。
- [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](/help/on-topic)は、本サイトで取り扱う種類（オントピック/オフトピック）に関するサイト特有のヘルプ記事です。このページの内容はネットワーク上のサイトごとに異なります。

### 基本的なワークフロー

レビュータスクページの上部に、他のユーザーによって通報された理由が表示されますが、その理由に同意できない場合は別のオプションを選択できます。クローズされている場合、投票数が最も多いクローズ理由が投稿に表示されます。質問の内容を全て確認し、次のいずれかのオプションから選択してください :

- 重複している、詳細が不足している、範囲を狭める必要がある、意見に基づいている、オフトピック、またはコミュニティ特有の理由である場合には、質問を**クローズ**してください。あなたの評価に基づき、該当するクローズ理由を選択してください。
- 上記のいずれにも当てはまらない場合は、**オープンのままにする**を選択してください。
- **編集**は、質問がクローズするに値しそうでも改善して範囲内におさまる可能性のあるときのために取っておく必要があります。これは、投稿者のコメントに残された詳細を追加したり、意見に基づく質問を事実に基づくものにするため調整するような場合です。質問がレビューから取り除かれてしまうため、これらの変更があっても質問がクローズされる場合に小さな編集を行わないでください。
- 投稿の品質がよくわからない場合は**スキップ**してください。スキップボタンを使用することを躊躇しないでください！処理方法を推測しなくてはならない投稿ではなく、確実にレビューを行える投稿に重点を置いてください。

**ヒント**：おなじみのタグでレビューをフィルタリングすることによって表示する質問をあなたがよく知っているものに制限することができます。これを行うには、レビュータスクの上部にある[フィルタ]をクリックします。よくわからない場合はスキップを選択してください。

[image: Close votes filters]

注意：2つのタグを選択すると、1つまたは両方のタグが付いたすべてのレビューが表示されます。フィルタは、両方のタグを含むものだけのレビューに制限することはできません。

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing Close Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032)"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 再オープン票キューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-CloseQuestion で利用可能*
クローズされ再オープン投票を1度受けた質問や、クローズから70日以内に編集された質問が、このキューに追加されます。このキューを確認する前に、どのような種類の質問をクローズすべきで、反対にクローズすべきではないかを、理解しておく必要があります。その詳細情報については、次の2つのヘルプページを参照してください :

- [質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](/help/closed-questions)のヘルプ記事はネットワーク全体のガイドで質問をクローズする必要がある主な理由が述べられています。クローズは通常、次の場合に発生します :

  - サイト上で既に存在する質問の[重複](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)である。
  - 回答するためにより詳細に、または明確にする必要がある。
  - 既存の質問の範囲が広すぎるため、より焦点を絞る必要がある。
  - 客観的に正しい答えが得られそうにもない、意見に基づく質問である。
- [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](/help/on-topic)は本サイトで取り扱う種類（オントピック/オフトピック）に関するサイト特有のヘルプ記事です。このページの内容はネットワーク上のサイトごとに異なります。

### 基本的なワークフロー

質問をその状態のまま評価してください。質問がクローズされた後に編集とコメントが残されたかどうかを確認し、編集が行われた場合には、なぜ再オープンには不十分なのか理由を説明するコメントを残してください。

- クローズ理由がまだ当てはまる場合は**クローズのままに**します。クローズ理由がもはや当てはまらない場合は再オープンせず、質問はクローズされたままにします。クローズ理由がバナーに表示されているものと異なる場合は特に、質問をクローズのままにする理由を説明するコメントを残すようにしてください。
- 質問の問題点を自分で解決し、その編集が再オープン条件に満たす場合は**編集して再オープン**して下さい。投稿を再オープンできるかどうかという点に影響を与えないような小さな編集は避けてください。
- 質問の問題点が解決された場合や質問が過ってクローズされた場合には**再オープン**してください。
- 投稿を再オープンするべきかどうかわからない場合は**スキップ**してください。

**ヒント**：おなじみのタグでレビューをフィルタリングすることによって表示する質問をあなたがよく知っているものに制限することができます。これを行うには、レビュータスクの上部にある[フィルタ]をクリックします。よくわからない場合はスキップを選択してください。

[image: Reopen votes filter]

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450)

"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 遅延回答キューを使用するには？

*信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues で利用可能*
遅延回答キューには、質問が投稿されてから回答が投稿されるまでの経過時間が比較的長いものが含まれています。遅れて投稿された回答は、質問が投稿された直後の回答よりも少ない数のユーザーの目にとまるため、レビューキューを通して遅延回答が他の回答のようにサイトの品質基準を満たしていることを確認します。

遅れて投稿された回答の多くは単に「ありがとう！うまくいきました」だけであったり、同じ問題に関するフォローアップのもの（「私も同じ問題があります」など）であるため、それらは削除する必要があります。トピックに関する特定の知識を必要とする場合もあり、回答が質問に実際に回答しようとしているかどうか疑わしい場合は、 [スキップ] オプションを使用してください。

### 基本的なワークフロー

レビューを行う時には、1つだけ或いはいくつかのアクションを実行することもできますし、何も実行しないという場合もあるでしょう。あなたが必要だと判断したアクションを実行してください。例えば、良い回答であってもフォーマットのヘルプが必要な場合などです。その場合はフォーマットを改善できるように編集し、必要に応じて [完了] をクリックする前にプラス票を投じることもできます。

- この投稿に対して対処する必要がない場合は［**対処の必要なし**］
- 以下のアクションを行った場合は［**完了**］を選択して下さい :

  - プラス票やマイナス票を**投じる**。
  - 投稿は明確でガイドラインを満たしていたものの、文法やスペル、フォーマットなどの改善が必要で**編集**（或いは編集の提案）を行う。
  - **コメント**欄に何が欠落しているか調整が必要なのかを指摘する。これらのコメントは投稿者と他のレビューアーの両方に役立ちます。
  - スパムや暴言、またはリンクのみで回答に質問に回答しようとしない投稿を**通報**する。
  - [信頼できるユーザー](/help/privileges/trusted-user)は、質問に回答しようとしない、リンクのみ、他の回答と重複している回答の削除に投票することが可能です。
- 確信が持てない場合には [**スキップ**]

### 一般的な遅延回答

- スパムや自己PR

  - 回答が[スパム発信者にならないようにどうすればいいですか？](/help/promotion)の条件を満たしている場合は、他のレビューアーによってスパムとマークされてしまわないようにコメントを追加してください。条件を満たしていない場合は、ヘルプセンターの記事にリンクするコメントを追加し、ガイドラインに合うように投稿を編集するよう促してください。明らかにスパムのように見える場合は、そのように通報してください。
- 回答になっていない回答

  - 質問の投稿者や回答の1つに「ありがとう」と言っているだけの回答や、回答欄に新しい質問をしてしまっているもの、「私も同じ問題があります」と述べるだけのもの、或いは投稿者に説明を求める回答などは削除される必要があります。

効果的に編集する方法の詳細については、ヘルプ記事「[自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか？編集はどのように機能しますか？](/help/editing)」をご覧ください。

このページのコンテンツの一部は、Meta Stack Exchange FAQ から要約されています。このキューについてのより詳細な情報を知りたい場合は、"[Guidelines for reviewing Late Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031)"（英語）を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 初めての回答投稿キューを使用するには？

---

*信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues で利用可能*

初めての回答投稿キューには、回答をするための最良の方法をまだ完全に理解できていないかもしれない新規ユーザーによって作成された最初の投稿が含まれます。スタック・オーバーフローに参加する際のルールなどサポートが必要であるかもしれないユーザーや、改善を必要とする可能性の高い投稿などに少し注意を払うことが、このキューの目的です。

### 基本的なワークフロー

- 投稿に対して対処する必要がない場合は **OK** を選択してください。
- 投稿は明確でガイドラインを満たしていたものの、文法やスペル、フォーマットなどの改善が必要な場合は **編集** （或いは編集の提案）を行ってください。
- 投稿が良い回答となる可能性があるものの、投稿者以外誰にも改善できそうにない場合には、**フィードバックを共有** してください。標準化された応答から選択するか、カスタムコメントを残してください。標準化されたコメントをコミュニティボットとして投稿することも、自分自身として投稿し通知を受け取ることもできます。
- 投稿を通報する必要がある場合、またはインタラクションの組み合わせが必要な場合は、**その他のアクション** を選択します。
- 何をすべきか確信が持てない場合には **スキップ** してください。

タスクを却下するにはユーザーからの1回のレビューで十分です。よって、回答が本サイトの期待値に届くかどうかを注意深くレビューするように心がけてください。レビューを行い、実行するアクションを決めるためのガイドラインはこちらです：

- 稿者が、単純なコメントや新しい質問の投稿ではなく、焦点を絞った回答をしようとしているかどうかを確認してください。
- 「その他の回答」タブ（存在する場合）を確認して、これまでに投稿された他の回答とは異なることを確認してください。
- リンクが壊れていない、またはリンクだけで構成されていない投稿でなければなりません。
- 投稿がスパムであったりプロモーションリンクが含まれている場合は、「スパム」として通報してください。
- 投稿が不快な場合は「失礼または暴言」として通報してください。

効果的に編集する方法の詳細については、ヘルプ記事「[自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか？編集はどのように機能しますか？](/help/editing)」をご覧ください。

Answer (score 2):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 初めての質問投稿キューを使用するには？

---

*信用度 $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues で利用可能*

初めての投稿キューには、質問をするための最良の方法やスタック・オーバーフローでのオントピック/オフトピックをまだ完全に理解できていないかもしれない新規ユーザーによって作成された最初の投稿が含まれます。スタック・オーバーフローに参加する際のルールなどサポートが必要であるかもしれないユーザーや、改善を必要とする可能性の高い投稿などに少し注意を払うことが、このキューの目的です。

### 基本的なワークフロー

- 投稿に対して対処する必要がない場合は **OK** を選択してください。
- 投稿は明確でガイドラインを満たしていたものの、文法やスペル、フォーマットなどの改善が必要な場合は **編集** （或いは編集の提案）を行ってください。
- 投稿に良い答えがつく可能性があるものの、投稿者以外誰にも改善できそうにない場合には、**フィードバックを共有** してください。標準化された応答から選択するか、カスタムコメントを残してください。標準化されたコメントをコミュニティボットとして投稿することも、自分自身として投稿し通知を受け取ることもできます。
- 投稿を通報する必要がある場合、またはインタラクションの組み合わせが必要な場合は、**その他のアクション** を選択します。
- 何をすべきか確信が持てない場合には **スキップ** してください。

タスクを却下するにはユーザーからの1回のレビューで十分です。よって、質問が本サイトの期待値に届くかどうかを注意深くレビューするように心がけてください。レビューを行い、実行するアクションを決めるためのガイドラインはこちらです：

- 質問の主要部分がオフサイトでホストされずに投稿に含まれていることを確認してください。他のサイトへのリンクがある場合はリンクが壊れたり変更されても質問自体が成り立つ様に書かれていなければなりません。
- 良い質問とは :

  - 明確である。
  - 回答するために必要なすべての情報が含まれている。
  - オントピックである。
  - 事実に基づいた回答を求めている。
  - リサーチ済みである。
  - 適切なタグが付けられている。
- 必要に応じて、不足している情報をコメントで尋ねて質問の範囲を狭めるか、サイトの質問範囲に合うように質問を言い換えるようにしましょう。
- 以前に見たことがあるように思われる質問は、投稿が重複していないかをご確認ください。
- 新しいユーザーを励ますためにも、上手く書かれた質の良い質問にプラス票を投じてください。
- 投稿がスパムであったりプロモーションリンクが含まれている場合は、「スパム」として通報してください。
- 投稿が不快な場合は「失礼または暴言」として通報してください。
- 質問をクローズしなければならない場合もあります。通報する、或いはクローズ票を投じて質問をクローズすることができます。質問のクローズについてはこちらをご覧ください。[通報する](/help/privileges/flag-posts)、或いはクローズ票を投じて質問をクローズする ことができます。質問のクローズについては[こちら](/help/closed-questions)をご覧ください。

効果的に編集する方法の詳細については、ヘルプ記事「[自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか？編集はどのように機能しますか？](/help/editing)」をご覧ください。