# レビューキュー関連で追加されたヘルプページが未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

少し前にレビューキューの仕組みが見直されました。

[Review queue workflows - Final release - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013)

この変更に伴い、「初めての投稿」キューが「初めての質問」「初めての回答」キューに分割され、ヘルプセンターにもページが追加されていますが英語のままです。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers

関連して、[レビューキューの一覧ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues) に「初めての投稿」が残っていますが、上記の翻訳が済めば不要となるはずです。
(英語版では "初めての投稿" のページ自体と、ページへのリンクが削除されています)

Answer (score 0):

「[初めての質問投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions)」と「[初めての回答投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers)」の和訳がヘルプに追加され、「初めての投稿」の削除が完了しました。
[image]

（「[レビューキューとは何ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro)」をピン留めするところまではできたのですが、諸事情により上からの順序を整えるまでには至りませんでした...。）